# Admob Support for Kivy (Python for Android)

Tags: android, python, admob, kivy, revmob

I have seen the RevMob SDK and a few other things that I have gotten to work, but I want to use Admob so that I can get paid directly through Google. I know that Kivy uses Python for Android, so is there a way I could use Admob in Kivy?

Also, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162834/admob-integration-with-pygame-in-android) question, but it had no answers, and was poorly written.

Comment: I see you tagged this as python-3.x. You should be aware that python-for-android does not yet work with Python3+.

Comment: Thank you @brousch! I usually develop in python 3, but am currently using Python 2 for this project, the tag was a mistake.

Comment: Some one already has implemented it but hasn't (yet) published the source code. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.alborini.admob4kivy

Comment: I found a Step by step tutorial at http://www.theseusmedia.com/blogs/code . I'm currently testing it. I'll post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: @Wally good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer right now is "maybe". As far as I know, no one has tried it yet. You would have to use pyjnius to access the Android/Admob API.

Comment: I am working on this now, actually. When I saw the new Kivy Crash Course (#12), I thought of the same thing, as Alexander Taylor shows how to use pyjnius in it.

Comment: Cool. Let us know how it went.